# A transaction call only if two addresses agree

Tags: signature, gnosis-safe, multisignature

I have a smart contract and i want a function (transaction) only be called if two addresses agree (maybe signs it or whatever), How can i solve this ? should i use Gnosis Safe to create  a multisig wallet and send the transaction with that wallet ? or i can implement it directly into the function logic ?

**PS**: if only the first alternative is possible do someone have a resource on how to do it since Safe documentation is very bad ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
bool addressOnePermision;
bool addressTwoPermision;

function setaddressOnePermision(bool _addressOnePermision) public {
    addressOnePermision = _addressOnePermision;
}

function setaddressOnePermision(bool _addressTwoPermision) public {
    addressTwoPermision = _addressTwoPermision;
}

function store() public {
    require(addressOnePermision);
    require(addressTwoPermision);

    //your logic here

    addressOnePermision = false;
    addressTwoPermision = false;
}
```